# Self value in Module within Module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

Why given a module like this:

```
module TestModule
  module Configuration
    # Return the configuration values set in this module
    def options
      puts "OPTIONS IS IN"
      puts self.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

I get that the options method is in TestModule and not in Configuration?

EDIT: I add the gem that I am taking a look at, and the one that has given me this confusion:

Check this file: [configuration.rb](https://github.com/gregmoreno/awesome/blob/master/lib/awesome/configuration.rb) in line 37 the method  `options`  is defined.

In the class [Client](https://github.com/gregmoreno/awesome/blob/master/lib/awesome/client.rb) however, when options is called (line 11) is used doing Awesome instead of Configuration. Why is that? I don't see any class named Awesome where those modules are being mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem in question does (in awesome.rb)

```
module Awesome
  extend Configuration
end
```

So all of the methods on `Awesome::Configuration` (such as `options`) become singleton methods on the `Awesome` module

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it's not part of either. It would have to be mixed in to a class to make it part of a class. To make it callable directly on the module, you need to prefix it with `self.` in the definition to make it a module method instead of an instance method:

```
def self.options
  self #=> TestModule::Configuration
end
```

Here's a good tutorial on mixins which allows you to use the instance methods: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/modules_mixins.html

Comment: Linuxios thanks for the answer. I think I don't understand truly what do you mean though. I have edited my question and added the gem that I am analyzing and that has given me the doubts.  Could you help me with that?